# How to copy a driver into a directory for Intel ax200 wireles device

Tags: drivers

ubuntu,. I'm traying to copy a dirver for intel ax200 wireles. i have the following message:

```
cp /home/alberto/Downloads/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode lib/firmware
cp: cannot create regular file 'lib/firmware': No such file or directory
```

Into Intel installation instruccions says copy the iwlwifi.....in that directory. any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your wireless now working with just the firmware? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lib/firmware` is only valid if you did a `cd /`before it. Otherwise the command needs to be:

```
sudo cp /home/alberto/Downloads/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware
```

2 alterations:

- sudo
- a `/`in front of `lib/firmware`